# How do I properly cancel all pending asyncio tasks and properly close all the loops across all threads in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety, exit

**Goal:** To cancel pending tasks safely across all threads. Then safely end all the asyncio loops across all threads.

**Code explanation:**
I opened two threads, one for the server to run and the other for background processing. Each thread has there own separate asyncio loops.

**Desired Function:**
When I receive a message called `onClose` from the client, I want to immediately shutdown all processes safely across all the threads. Desired Function is in the `func_websocket_connection()` function after `print('Running On Close Function')`

**Techniques Tried:**
Of course I tried `os._exit(0)` to abruptly stop everything. It accomplishes what I want but I also know it is not safe and can corrupt processing data. I also tried

```
print('Running On Close Function')
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop = loop.stop()
```

which also works but I get `Task was destroyed but it is pending!`

**Non-Server Code:**

```
import asyncio
import websockets
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

#=============================================
# Open Websocket Server:
def func_run_server():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    asyncio.ensure_future(func_websocket_connection())
    loop.run_forever()

# Background Processing Function 1:
async def func_websocket_connection():
    while i in range(100):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5) 
        print('Run Step Server 0')
        #Some If Statement
        if i == 10:
            print('Running On Close Function')
#=============================================
# Open Background Processing:
def func_run_background():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    future_run_step0 = asyncio.ensure_future(func_run_step0())
    future_run_step1 = asyncio.ensure_future(func_run_step1())
    loop.run_until_complete(future_run_step0)
    loop.run_until_complete(future_run_step1)

# Background Processing Function 1:
async def func_run_step0():
    await asyncio.sleep(5.0) 
    print('Run Step 0')

# Background Processing Function 2:
async def func_run_step1():
    await asyncio.sleep(5.0) 
    print('Run Step 1')
#================================================================================
#Running two separate threads
Thread(target=func_run_server).start()
Thread(target=func_run_background).start()
```

Comment: Can you write an [mcve] that does not rely on sockets and socket *traffic* to test?

Comment: sure @wwii , i changed the code